# Functional solution instead of iterative

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have to implement the following task. I created the following table for simplicity:

[image]

We have input and a table with defined rules. If any rule matches this input then apply the action to it.

For example input `HBC1234`:

1. starts_with H => true.
2. Thus, replace matching_value (H) with `M` => result is `MBC1234`.

In the same way iterate all other rules for this input.

Here is entity for replacement rule:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ReplacementRule implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MatchingOperation matchingOperation;
    @NotNull
    private String matchingValue;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ReplacementOperation replacementOperation;
    private String replacementValue;
}
```

And implementation for this task:

```
private static String apply(ReplacementRule rule, String plateNumber) {
    switch (rule.getMatchingOperation()) {
        case STARTS_WITH:
            if (plateNumber.startsWith(rule.getMatchingValue())) {
                return switch (rule.getReplacementOperation()) {
                    case REPLACE -> plateNumber.replaceFirst(rule.getMatchingValue(), rule.getReplacementValue());
                    case REMOVE -> plateNumber.substring(rule.getMatchingValue().length());
                };
            }
        case CONTAINS:
            if (plateNumber.contains(rule.getMatchingValue())) {
                return switch (rule.getReplacementOperation()) {
                    case REPLACE -> plateNumber.replaceAll(rule.getMatchingValue(), rule.getReplacementValue());
                    case REMOVE -> plateNumber.replaceAll(rule.getMatchingValue(), "");
                };
            }
        case ENDS_WITH:
            if (plateNumber.endsWith(rule.getMatchingValue())) {
                return switch (rule.getReplacementOperation()) {
                    case REPLACE -> plateNumber.substring(0, getEndIndex(rule, plateNumber)).concat(rule.getReplacementValue());
                    case REMOVE -> plateNumber.substring(0, getEndIndex(rule, plateNumber));
                };
            }
        case EQUALS:
            if (plateNumber.equals(rule.getMatchingValue())) {
                return switch (rule.getReplacementOperation()) {
                    case REPLACE -> rule.getReplacementValue();
                    case REMOVE -> "";
                };
            }
    }
    return "";
}

private static int getEndIndex(ReplacementRule rule, String plateNumber) {
    return plateNumber.length() - rule.getMatchingValue().length();
}
```

And final usage looks like:

```
public Optional<WhiteList> checkReplacementRules(String plateNumber) {
    List<ReplacementRule> allRules = ruleRepository.findAll();

    Optional<WhiteList> result = Optional.empty();
    for (ReplacementRule rule : allRules) {
        String newPlate = transform(rule, plateNumber);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(newPlate)) {
            result = whiteListRepository.findByNumberPlate(newPlate);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It combines matching and logic for replacing at one method `apply()`. However, it violates [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). But it works. Despite the fact that the solution is not the best.

Seems that this kind of task matches functional programming concepts.

How can I redesign it to a functional style?

Java version is **15**.

Comment: Why do you think it violates Open-Closed Principle?  `case`s to consider will be added?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi who knows. It is always un[redictable which requirements/conditions will be added in the future.

Comment: Isn't it avoidable to change code if new requirements are added? I think your code can consistently add rules and satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Is an abstraction of the “replacement operation” really necessary? There is no difference between “remove” and “replace with an empty string” and the string is carried anyway.

Comment: @Holger good shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the `enum` classes implement the action, i.e. the operation.

Regex seems like a perfect fit for what you're doing.

```java
private static String apply(ReplacementRule rule, String plateNumber) {
    String regex = rule.getMatchingOperation().regexFor(rule.getMatchingValue());
    String replacement = rule.getReplacementOperation().regexFor(rule.getReplacementValue());
    return Pattern.compile(regex)
                  .matcher(plateNumber)
                  .replaceFirst(replacement);
}
```

```java
public enum MatchingOperation {
    STARTS_WITH(v -> "^" + Pattern.quote(v)),
    CONTAINS   (v -> Pattern.quote(v)),
    ENDS_WITH  (v -> Pattern.quote(v) + "$"),
    EQUALS     (v -> "^" + Pattern.quote(v) + "$");

    private final UnaryOperator<String> asRegex;

    private MatchingOperation(UnaryOperator<String> asRegex) {
        this.asRegex = asRegex;
    }

    public String regexFor(String matchingValue) {
        return this.asRegex.apply(matchingValue);
    }
}
```

```java
public enum ReplacementOperation {
    REPLACE(Matcher::quoteReplacement),
    REMOVE (v -> "");

    private final UnaryOperator<String> asRegex;

    private ReplacementOperation(UnaryOperator<String> asRegex) {
        this.asRegex = asRegex;
    }

    public String regexFor(String replacementValue) {
        return this.asRegex.apply(replacementValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a `UnaryOperator<String>` and using `Pattern.compile` outside the class, it would make more sense to use a `Function<String,Pattern>`. Then you can use `Pattern.compile(v, Pattern.LITERAL)` for `CONTAINS`. Even better would be including the actual match operation into `MatchingOperation` (as its class name already suggests) and return a `Matcher`, as then, you can use `lookingAt` or `matches` instead of `find` and don’t need to do string concatenation to add anchors to the pattern.

Comment: @Holger could you show implementation for your suggestion. It will be much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your design violates Open-Closed Principle, however, here is my implementation. As it can add future requirements as functions, it can be called functional.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Rule {
    public String apply(String string);
}
```

`Rule` is for a function for each requirement.

```
class Replacement {
    ArrayList<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();

    public Replacement addRule(Rule rule) {
        rules.add(rule);
        return this;
    }
    
    public String applyAll(String string) {
        System.out.printf("%s --> ", string);
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            string = rule.apply(string);
        }   
        System.out.println(string);
        return string;
    }
}
```

`Replacement` can `addRule` and `applyAll` rules to the input.

And here is how `Rule`s are added as functions and be applied:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Replacement r = new Replacement()
        
        .addRule((String string) -> {
            if (string.startsWith("H"))
                return "M" + string.substring(1);
            return string;
        })
 
        .addRule((String string) -> {
            return string.replaceAll("A", "");
        })
        
        .addRule((String string) -> {
            if (string.endsWith("8"))
                return string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
            return string;
        })
        
        .addRule((String string) -> {
            if (string.equals("ABC12B467"))
                return "ABC123467";
            return string;
        });

        r.applyAll("HBC1234");
        r.applyAll("ABC1234");
        r.applyAll("ABC9988");
        r.applyAll("ABC12B467");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have all rules stored at DB. So I have to get them all from DB and apply for search one by one.

Comment: @catch23 You just need to define a function how to load a rule from DB and apply it then pass the function to `addRule`. You already had the solution, however, you asked a functional way to do it.